# Setting terminal type in inittab file

Tags: linux, bash, console

I've set the terminal type to monochrome one in `inittab` file like so:

```
c2:... tty2 linux-m
```

but when I type a command with colored output like:

```
ls --color=always -l
```

I still get colored result. How can it be if the terminal is set to non-color (tty definition in inittab file like above).

Comment: Why are you actually trying to setup a purely monochrome terminal in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The terminal type only *describes* a particular way to use a terminal.  There are no guarantees that a terminal actually behaves that way, nor is there any guarantee that a program uses other information for manipulating the terminal.

In this case, the `ls` program uses its own hard-coded database, which says that "linux" does color.

Further reading: ncurses FAQ *[Applications miscited as library users](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#not_library_users)*

Comment: Sorry but i can't clearly understand. If the terminal emulator defined by tty2 entry does not support colors  how can it disply them when doing 'ls'?

Comment: As I said: `ls` does not pay attention to the terminal description, and the terminal can do this whether you use the terminal description or not :-)

Comment: Do what? color 'ls' output?. How can the terminal handles colors if it have been set to  'linux-m' that's monochrome?

Comment: Can You answer my last question?

Comment: I already did: in my comment above your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before those programs are likely directly outputting [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors):

> As 256-color lookup tables became common on graphic cards, escape sequences were added to select from a pre-defined set of 256 colors:[citation needed]
>
> ```
> ESC[ … 38;5;<n> … m Select foreground color
>  ESC[ … 48;5;<n> … m Select background color
>  0-  7:  standard colors (as in ESC [ 30–37 m)
>  8- 15:  high intensity colors (as in ESC [ 90–97 m)
> 16-231:  6 × 6 × 6 cube (216 colors): 16 + 36 × r + 6 × g + b (0 ≤ r, g, b ≤ 5)
> ```
>
> 232-255:  grayscale from black to white in 24 steps

This argument would also be strengethend by answers for a similar question titled [Disable colours on terminal and SSH on the Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58982/disable-colours-on-terminal-and-ssh).

In your previous questions for this topic you mentioned you're using xterm. The [xterm man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm) also lists a `-cm` option to disable recognition of ANSI escape sequences. This is also mentioned in the answers to the linked question:

> -cm
>
> This option disables recognition of ANSI color-change escape sequences. It sets the colorMode resource to "false".

What you're doing by setting the terminal information is that you define the capabilities of the terminal (as per [man terminfo](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=terminfo&sektion=5)). As such, what you're doing equates to telling `ls` and so on that you're sure you can do certain things but that doesn't mean they have to honor it in any way.